# How to add dot '.' in the name of individuals in Sparql?

Tags: sparql

Is it possible to have a `.` (dot) in the qname of individuals or RDF resources in general?

Something like this?

```
SELECT  ?tableName ?fieldName 
WHERE { ?fieldName hrdata:relatedField hrdata:ps_ti0002.EMPLID. }
```

The dot in `ps_ti0002.EMPLID` is problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code is right and should work. It is possible to use dot in the individual's name.

I think you should check your data property (relatedField), maybe is not clarified right.

Answer (score 1):

@Narges Kasaeizadeh

Unfortunately, I still can't comment - but I think your answer is wrong and a dot is not allowed in prefixed URIs/IRIs as you can try out using the validator suggested by @AndyS .

Comment: It works for me. I don't know what you mean exactly. I wanted to model a Database tables and columns with OWL and I could use dot in naming.

Answer (score -1):

The `.` is allowed in SPARQL and the [SPARQLer Query Validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html) demonstrates.  However, there are a couple of suggestions to help you get this working.  First is to have a space after the qname, i.e.:

```
WHERE { ?fieldName hrdata:relatedField hrdata:ps_ti0002.EMPLID . }
```

Another is to use the fully qualified URI.  Suppose the namespace for `hrdata` is `http://example.org/hrdata/`, the the following query should work:

```
SELECT  ?tableName ?fieldName 
WHERE { ?fieldName hrdata:relatedField <http://example.org/hrdata/ps_ti0002.EMPLID> . }
```

Comment: It is not allowed, Just I have tested it again.

Comment: The second format should work for sure.  What SPARQL tool are you using?  Also do try the validator - it also demonstrates that your SPARQL tool may have a bug.